# How to have Drill Through Filters carry through buttons in PowerBI

Tags: button, filter, powerbi, drilldown, drillthrough

I have a matrix where I can drill through to another report using the company name variable. On the drill through page, I have buttons linking to other reports and I want the company name filter that was applied in the drill through to still be applied when I click the button to navigate to another report.

Example -- start at Travel Overview report, drill through to Air Detail report for company ABC. From that page I want to click a button to see the Hotel Detail report still for company ABC.

Currently, if my previous drill through was Travel Overview report -> Hotel Detail report for company XYZ, and then I go back to Travel Overview -> Air Detail company ABC and want to click the button to see Hotel Detail for company ABC it will show Hotel Detail for company XYZ since that is what the most company that the Travel Overview was drilled directly to Hotel Detail on.

Any ideas on how to get this drill through filtering to carry through on buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to layer the reports on one page with bookmarks and use the buttons to navigate to the different bookmarks, keeping the same company card in all bookmarks.